# Write automated script to upload random files from a folder path in Postman (Run with CI/CD system)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, postman-pre-request-script

I'm testing for API_Upload file
I have a folder which contains some file types.
How to write automated script to choose & upload random file from the folder?

I expect the uploaded files which are random and it can work well with CI/CD system